# Smallest Ideal in $M_2(Z)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

What is the smallest ideal in $M_2(Z)$ containing $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$? I'm a bit unsure about what "smallest" means here. I've found all of the ideals of $M_2(Z)$, however. Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Smallest" in this context means "doesn't contain any other ideals which contains this element". If you know all the ideals, then it ought to be easy.

Comment: This ring is not commutative: are you talking about right ideals, left ideals, or two-sided ideals?

Comment: For a ring with unity and $a \in R$ then $R a R$ is a two-sided ideal, here you'd want to describe $RaR$ in a more succinct way, same for $aR,Ra$